# Replace JPA/Hibernate DiscriminatorColumn with SQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have to maintain some JPA/Hibernate code that is used to manage some database tables. I have a class hierarchy like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table_name")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="column_name", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class AbstractBaseClass {...}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("N")
public class SubClass1 extends AbstractBaseClass { ...}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Y")
public class SubClass2 extends AbstractBaseClass { ...}
```

This is all working fine, but the database is being redesigned, the discriminatory column will be removed, and the type of the records will be determined by an SQL query. This redesign was not my idea, and I have no control over the database structure. It is also not practical to change the Java hierarchy, because of the existing code base. What can I use instead of DiscriminatorColumn/DiscriminatorValue so that everything continues to work?

Comment: What sort of SQL query? Based on other properties or a join with other tables?

Comment: Some other table has two columns (col1, col2) that are foreign keys pointing to our table. If the id of the current row is contained in the col1 of the other table, then we have type 1, and otherwise the other type.

Comment: Are you sure that your domain model is correct? If the DB guys think your two subclasses need to be in the same table, and they're different only because they are used differently (e.g. referred to as col1 vs. col2), maybe they are not different subclasses, and you need to refactor the differences out. 

Maybe it's another case for "prefer composition over inheritance".

Comment: Thank you, but this is about the maintenance of a very complicated and badly designed app (it was not me, who wrote it...). The design is bad in many ways, but it works. I try to keep the changes to a minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the discriminator can be determined using a simple SQL formula, you can use the hibernate-specific @DiscriminatorFormula extension:

```
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@org.hibernate.annotations.DiscriminatorFormula("(CASE WHEN ... THEN 'SubClass1' ELSE 'SubClass2' END)")
public abstract class AbstractBaseClass {

}
```

Don't know why they didn't include this in the JPA standard :-(.

Comment: I tried @DiscriminatorFormula("(CASE WHEN (ID in (select fk1 from other_table)) THEN 'SubClass1' ELSE 'SubClass2' END)"), but I get java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904 because of a malformed SQL. Are you sure that this should work even if the SQL inside CASE WHEN refers to another table?

Comment: Never tried it with oracle. Can you get the actual generated SQL?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that Hibernate modifies my nested SQL select, instead of "select fk1 from other_table" it tries "select alias.fk1 from other_table", where alias refers to the original table, which of course does not have this column.

Comment: But it seems to work if I provide explicit aliasing! Still checking if everything is correct...

Answer (score 2):

If you have absolutely no influence over the table design and the future design will come as a big surprise, than the situation looks bleak :)

But maybe you could still use your entities with minor changes. The good news is that JPA offers 2 more inheritance mapping models in addition to `SINGLE_TABLE` - `JOINED` and `TABLE_PER_CLASS`.

**JOINED:**  You would end up wiht three tables, one for each entity, including the abstract one. The tables will contain exactly the attributes that are contained in the respective classes. To access different types, the provider will have to access (and join) different tables, so no discriminator column is necessary.

**TABLE_PER_CLASS:** You wil lhave two tables, one for each of your concrete subclasses. Each of them will map all attributes of the abstract parent class plus their own attributes. As before, the provider will be working with separate tables, so no discriminator is needed.

In order to make the transition, you have to change the line

```
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
```

to either

```
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
```

or

```
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
```

The good thing for JPQL queries is that they do not have to change at all. Just use the JPQL  `TYPE` keyword and the provider will do all the mapping.

**EDIT:** one more thing - in case you will have to cope with the single table but with no discriminators, and the type will be determined by a join, you can use JPQL constructor expressions like this:

`SELECT NEW com.example.SubClass1(e.name, e.address) FROM CommonSurrogateEntity e, TypeHintEntity t WHERE t.type = e.foreignKey`

The `CommonSurrogateEntity` would be a fake class, mapping the entire common table. `TypeHintEntity` would be this other table you were talking about in the comment.

Comment: Where do I put this JPQL constructor? You mean the entityManager.createQuery parameter?

Comment: Never mind, the other Hibernate-specific solution works with only local changes. Anyway +1 for you as well.